# Accessing container on port 3000 thru traefik

Tags: traefik

Okay, so I've got a node-js app I'd like to access thru traefik.

The node-js app runs on port `3000`

I've got traefik running after following the `test-it` instructions from the getting started page.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - NODE_PORT=3000
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    expose:
      - "3000"
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=microservice"
      - "traefik.backend.port=3000"
      - "traefik.port=3000"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:microservice.docker.localhost"
networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik_webgateway
```

### Trying to connect:

`curl -H Host:microservice.docker.localhost http://localhost/`

> Bad Gateway

`curl -H Host:microservice.docker.localhost http://localhost:3000/`

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

But `curl -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost http://localhost/` works like intended.

Comment: The `traefik.backend.port` options doesn't look right, but you should be OK with only setting `traefik.port`. Can we see traefik config.toml and/or command line flags? Plus, I know it should be the same, could you try and map micro service.docker.localhost in your hosts file and curl the correct name directly? Where is the whoami.docker.localhost declared?

Comment: @whites11 the whoami.docker.localhost was declared in the getting started https://docs.traefik.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my microservice was bound to listen to `localhost:3000` instead I changed it to `0.0.0.0:3000` and it worked like a charm.

removed `- "traefik.backend.port=3000"` from the `docker-compose.yml`

added `127.0.0.1 microservice.docker.localhost` to `/etc/hosts`

which rendered me able to:

`curl http://microservice.docker.localhost/` and get the response I was expecting

> I'm a microservice!

Comment: Can someone post the answer with the v2 ? :(